# Why doesn't the linked views change after an animation?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, animation, android-animation

I am trying to create a simple animation; move a view down the Y-axis. In this example the view is testnote1 but the view attached to the bottom testnote2 doesn't change. Why is this?

I read using View.animate() just animates views visually while ObjectAnimator does more than that such as moving the click area with the view. Does ObjectAnimator not also cover other views linked to view being animated? i.e. Resizing testnote2 so that the top is still constrained to the bottom of testnote1 in this case.

Do I have to resize testnote2 separately or is there something more convenient such as View.update()? ConstraintSet seems to be overkill for just two views.

**Update:**

To take the original question further, I've added a nested layout view. Just like how note1 ends up overlapping note2 instead of pushing it down, it also just overlaps the content area of clcontent.

The remedy for the two text views would be to animate both textviews it seems but, what would have to be done to clcontent? If I just animate clcontent the views inside it ends up getting pushed down.

[image: Actual and expected]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#FFC107"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/testnote1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="content"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testnote2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#CDDC39"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/testnote1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/testnote1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#4CAF50"
        android:text="testnote1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```kotlin
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var clcontent: ConstraintLayout
    lateinit var text1: TextView
    lateinit var text2: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        text1 = findViewById(R.id.testnote1)
        text2 = findViewById(R.id.testnote2)
        clcontent = findViewById(R.id.clcontent)

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(text1, "translationY", text1.height.toFloat())
                .setDuration(1000).start()
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you translate a `view` it doesn't really move the whole `view` to that position but gives it an offset wrt to its original position. So, it would appear that the whole `view` has been moved.

If you would turn on, show layout bound you could see that view stays at its old position.

[image]

What you can do to achieve the expected behavior is `translate` both of the views simultaneuously.

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(text1, "translationY", text1.height.toFloat())
            .setDuration(1000).start()
    ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(text2, "translationY", text1.height.toFloat + testnote2.top)
            .setDuration(1000).start()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What if text2 was a nested layout view and I want it resized instead of being pushed down so that the content isn't shifted downwards?

Comment: I'm not getting what you're trying to say? Do you want to resize `text2`? Update your question with the details.

Comment: Ok, I've updated. Hopefully you get what I'm trying to say